# Can I improve on the current Python code?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I am just starting out with Python and decided to try this little project from [Python Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Conditional_Statements):

*Write a password guessing program to keep track of how many times the user has entered the password wrong. If it is more than 3 times, print You have been denied access. and terminate the program. If the password is correct, print You have successfully logged in. and terminate the program.*

Here's my code. It works but it just doesn't feel right with these **loop breaks** and **nested if statements**.

```
# Password Guessing Program
# Python 2.7

count = 0

while count < 3:
    password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
    if password != 'SecretPassword':
        count = count + 1;
        print 'You have entered invalid password %i times.' % (count)
        if count == 3:
            print 'Access Denied'
            break
    else:
        print 'Access Granted'
        break
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace your while loop with the following function:

```
def login():
    for i in range(3):
        password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
        if password != 'SecretPassword':
            print 'You have entered invalid password {0} times.'.format(i + 1)
        else:
            print 'Access Granted'
            return True
    print 'Access Denied'
    return False
```

You may also want to consider using the [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module.

Comment: Really minor nitpicking: That should be `.format(i+1)`. Also, `getpass` is the way to go for real code but not really needed for a beginner's excercise.

Comment: When I run this code I get nothing. How do I "call" this function?

Comment: @Silence of 2012: Like you would call any other function: `login()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not against the "imperative" feel of loop/if, but I would separate your "business logic" from your "presentation":

```
count = 0

# Business logic
# The correct password and the maximum number of tries is placed here
DENIED, VALID, INVALID = range(3)
def verifyPassword(userPassword):
    global count
    count += 1

    if count > 3:
        return DENIED
    elif password == 'SecretPassword':
        return VALID

    return INVALID

# Presentation
# Here you do the IO with the user
check = INVALID
while (check == INVALID):
    password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
    check = verifyPassword(password)

    if check == INVALID:
        print 'You have entered invalid password %i times.' % (count)
    elif check == VALID:
        print 'Access Granted'
    else # check == DENIED
        print 'Access Denied'
```

Comment: I think you want to declare `count` to be global.

Answer (score 2):

```
granted = False # default condition should be the least dangerous
for count in range(3):
    password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
    if password == 'SecretPassword': # no need to test for wrong answer
        granted = True
        break
    print 'You have entered invalid password %i times.' % (count+1) # else

if granted:
    print 'Access Granted'
else:
    print 'Access Denied'
```

Comment: Quick question, when you do this "for count in range(3):" what is the initial value of count?

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the if statement out of the while loop.

```
# Password Guessing Program
# Python 2.7

count = 0
access = False

while count < 3 and not access:
    password = raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
    if password != 'SecretPassword':
        count += 1
        print 'You have entered invalid password %i times.' % (count)
    else:
        access = True

if access:
    print 'Access Granted'
else:
    print 'Access Denied'
```

Comment: I'm not super experienced with python so there maybe some syntax problems.

Comment: Yes indeed it does contain sytnax errors. && is not valid in Python and then it complains that name 'false' is not defined.

Comment: There's a couple of changes that should fix the syntax (I think). I think the overall logic answers the question by getting rid of the breaks.

Comment: Fixed your syntax for you. :) Nevertheless, I think the concept is easy to grasp regardless of syntax errors.